# Function with for loop: Why is 1 not overwritten by 5?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

I have a problem with a for loop. The console log output is 1. I don't understand why the function does not return 5? To my understanding, 1 should be overwritten by 5? Where is the mistake?

Very appreciate your help.

```js
const hallo = {
  1: {"name": "Hallo"}, 
  2: {"name": "Frage", "id": 1}, 
  3: {"name": "Frage", "id": 5}, 
  4:  {"name": "Endpunkt"}
}
const inputcontext = () => {
  console.log(hallo[1]);
  var i;

  var l = Object.keys(hallo).length;
  for (i = 1; i < l; i++) {
    if (hallo[i].name === "Frage") {
      let inputcontext = hallo[i].id;
      return inputcontext;
    }
  }
}
const s = inputcontext()
console.log(s)
```

Comment: return exits the function immediately after the first occurrence.  It only iterates until "2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning from the function as soon as you get the first match. You need to complete all iterations of the loop and then return.

```js
const hallo = {
  1: {"name": "Hallo"}, 
  2: {"name": "Frage", "id": 1}, 
  3: {"name": "Frage", "id": 5}, 
  4:  {"name": "Endpunkt"}
}
const inputcontext = () => {
  console.log(hallo[1]);
  var i;
  let inputcontext = "";
  var l = Object.keys(hallo).length;
  for (i = 1; i < l; i++) {
    if (hallo[i].name === "Frage") {
      inputcontext = hallo[i].id;
    }
  }
  return inputcontext;
}
const s = inputcontext()
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

return statement just break the iteration, the position of the return statement matters. I hope this examples helps.

```js
function example(){
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(i == 5) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
console.log(example());     // returns 5

function example2(){
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(i == 5) {
            console.log('Hello world')
        }
    }
    return i;
}
console.log(example2());    // returns 10
```